# Data inserted in atomic transaction persists even after rollback

Tags: mysql, django, transactions

I am trying to implement this atomic transaction in django and am following [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) from the docs. But changes are found to persist despite rollback. I've searched for similar questions and most common cause seems to be catching integrity error inside atomic block, but I am not doing that.
Following is my django code:

```
def get_lead_alert_data(params):
    with transaction.atomic():
        with acquire_lead_lock():
            caller = params['caller']
            via = params['via']
            called = params['called']
            leadphone = LeadsPhone.objects.filter(phone_number=caller, brokerage__isnull=True).first()
            if leadphone:
                lead_id = leadphone.lead_id
            else:
                lead_id = create_lead_from_inbound_call(caller, called)
        created, requirement = get_or_create_requirement_from_inbound_call(via, lead_id)
        picking_agent = Users.objects.get(phone_mobile=called)
        if created:
            RequirementAssignment.objects.create(requirement=requirement, agent=picking_agent)
            assigned_to = picking_agent.user_name
        else:
            assigned_requirement = RequirementAssignment.objects.filter(brokerage__active=True,
                                                                        requirement=requirement).first() #There will be only one such requirement
            if not assigned_requirement.agent:
                assigned_requirement.agent = picking_agent
                assigned_requirement.save()
            assigned_to = assigned_requirement.agent.user_name if assigned_requirement else 'nobody'
    return {'lead_id': lead_id, 'assigned_to': assigned_to, 'picking_by': picking_agent.user_name}
```

I also checked resulting logs in mysql and it is indeed calling a rollback, yet the changes persist.

```
3043 Connect   root@localhost on reserve_db_2
                 3043 Query     SET NAMES utf8
                 3043 Query     set autocommit=0
                 3043 Query     set autocommit=1
                 3043 Query     SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
                 3043 Query     set autocommit=0
                 3043 Query     lock table person write, leads write, leads_phones write, leads_emails write, requirements write, tele_phones read
                 3043 Query     SELECT `leads_phones`.`id`, `leads_phones`.`lead_id`, `leads_phones`.`phone_number`, `leads_phones`.`brokerage_id`, `leads_phones`.`created` FROM `leads_phones` WHERE (`leads_phones`.`phone_number` = '9899696089' AND `leads_phones`.`brokerage_id` IS NULL) ORDER BY `leads_phones`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
                 3043 Query     INSERT INTO `person` (`user_id`, `fullname`, `mobile_no`, `fb_location`, `fb_email`, `fb_aboutme`, `fb_avatar`, `goog_email`, `goog_avatar`, `uploaded_avatar`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `description`, `address`, `is_admin`, `reviewer_badge`, `title`, `phone_home`, `phone_work`, `phone_other`, `phone_fax`, `status`, `address_street`, `address_city`, `address_region_id`, `address_country`, `address_postalcode`, `created`, `last_updated`, `created_by`, `modified_by`, `deleted`) VALUES (NULL, '', NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '1ST TIME REVIEWER', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2014-09-06 11:12:03', '2014-09-06 11:12:03', '', NULL, 0)
140906 16:40:05  3043 Query     INSERT INTO `leads` (`id`, `date_entered`, `date_modified`, `modified_user_id`, `created_by`, `description`, `deleted`, `assigned_user_id`, `salutation`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `title`, `department`, `do_not_call`, `primary_email_address`, `secondary_email_address`, `phone_home`, `phone_mobile`, `phone_work`, `phone_other`, `phone_fax`, `primary_address_street`, `primary_address_city`, `primary_address_state`, `primary_address_postalcode`, `primary_address_country`, `alt_address_street`, `alt_address_city`, `alt_address_state`, `alt_address_postalcode`, `alt_address_country`, `converted`, `refered_by`, `lead_source_description`, `status`, `status_description`, `reports_to_id`, `residence_phone`, `citizenship`, `primary_address_street_by_agent`, `office_location`, `owned_rented`, `owned_rented_by_agent`, `unique_id`, `reason_for_status_change`, `annual_income`, `annual_income_by_agent`, `designation`, `executive_level`, `executive_level_by_agent`, `present_company`, `website`, `lead_type_fav`, `lead_type_c`, `facebook_url`, `linkedin_url`, `twitter_url`, `google_plus_url`, `assigned_user_date`, `worked_by_tele`, `worked_by_sales`, `off_campaign_id`, `activity_done`, `activity_completed`, `queue_name`, `queue_description`, `history_notes`, `lead_category`, `trans_type`, `potential`, `referral_remark`, `referral_name`, `referral_no`, `referral_email`, `primary_secondary_lead`, `met_face_to_face`, `met_site_visit`, `met_final_negotiation`, `total_met`, `is_duplicate`, `is_duplicate_date`, `queue_abort_remark`, `referer_url`, `landing_url`, `leadpage_url`, `lead_projects`, `lead_projects_ids`, `lead_max_budget`, `lead_source`, `person_id`, `brokerage_id`, `lead_parent_id`) VALUES ('1440bb40-4f8a-4f87-917f-6aca0c758711', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', NULL, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', NULL, NULL, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 315601, NULL, NULL)
                 3043 Query     INSERT INTO `leads_phones` (`lead_id`, `phone_number`, `brokerage_id`, `created`) VALUES ('1440bb40-4f8a-4f87-917f-6aca0c758711', '9899696089', NULL, '2014-09-06 11:12:03')
                 3043 Query     SELECT `tele_phones`.`id`, `tele_phones`.`source_id`, `tele_phones`.`project_id`, `tele_phones`.`locality_id`, `tele_phones`.`cluster_id`, `tele_phones`.`city_id` FROM `tele_phones` WHERE `tele_phones`.`id` = '3314892' LIMIT 21
                 3043 Query     INSERT INTO `requirements` (`id`, `req_unique_id`, `lead_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `date_entered`, `date_modified`, `created_by`, `modified_user_id`, `assigned_user_id`, `deleted`, `req_type`, `category`, `bhk`, `unit_type`, `construction_phase`, `main_entrance_facing`, `balcony_facing`, `furnish_state`, `plc`, `locality`, `cluster`, `city`, `region`, `project`, `plot_area`, `super_area`, `price_sft_syd`, `price`, `total_price`, `cash_in_hand`, `need_loan`, `description`, `is_active_req`) VALUES ('63494d0d-88f8-44f5-816c-af4bb5ec439e', NULL, '1440bb40-4f8a-4f87-917f-6aca0c758711', NULL, '', NULL, NULL, '', '', '', NULL, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 1, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, 1)
                 3043 Query     unlock tables
                 3043 Query     rollback
                 3043 Query     set autocommit=1
```

Comment: Do youn use InnoDB tables?

Comment: Yes they're all innoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohk, I checked out mysql docs. Looks like unlocking tables [implicitly causes a commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html) if there are any locked tables, which there are in my case. Will have to find a workaround.